# SUB Query group by date and managers

Tags: mysql, sql

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAXil.png)

I have a table with actions by managers and date. Action can be `"0" or "1"`. 
i want to group by date and count `"0" and "1"` actions grouped by date and manager.
Here is my code.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) ,
  manager_id,
  action,
  CAST( `created_at` AS DATE ) AS DATE
FROM `prerequesttours_history`
GROUP BY CAST( `created_at` AS DATE ),
  anager_id,
  action
```

I want to result like this:

`| count where action = 1 | count where action = 0 | manager_id | date`

[Result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWVI0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `action` only takes on those two values, you can do:

```
SELECT manager_id, date(`created_at`) AS DATE,
       SUM(action) as count_1, SUM(1 - action) as cnt_0
FROM  `prerequesttours_history`
GROUP BY manager_id, date(created_at);
```

If you want to be more explicit about the comparison:

```
SELECT manager_id, date(`created_at`) AS DATE,
       SUM(action = 1) as count_1, SUM(action = 1) as cnt_0
FROM  `prerequesttours_history`
GROUP BY manager_id, date(created_at);
```

Note:  Using `cast()` to convert to a date is fine.  However, MySQL offers the simpler function `date()` for this purpose.

Comment: This is what I actually want. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting it as a sub-query.

```
SELECT SUM([Count]), manager_id, action, [Date]
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT( * ) 'Count' , manager_id, action, CAST(  `created_at` AS DATE ) 'Date'
) main
GROUP BY manager_id, action, [Date]
```